# How do you create bigger logical wholes in JS/jQuery (instead of putting everything into document.ready)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently simply have everything inside document.ready, which isn't very optimal for readability and DRYness.

What are the options to create modules/classes/namespaces/function or whatever you call them in jQuery/Javascript?

For example, how would you separate these concerns:

- A general purpose function that takes an element as parameter and appends the given string into it's name attribute?
- Code that prettifies the UI (applies button effects, styling, forms, tabs, etc.)?
- Code that handles AJAX

Apparently, what I want to know is: How do you structure code in JS? (Thanks Alex!)

Answer (score 2):

```
var myApp = {
  init: function () { },
  widget: {
    init: function () { },
    add:  function () { },
    del:  function () { },
    read: function () { },
    edit: function () { }
  },
  utils: {
    ui: {
      rotate: function () { },
      jump:   function () { }
    }
  }
};

myApp.init();
```

Comment: ahh, this is using JSON, correct? That's pretty nice. Will this be auto-loaded before document.ready?

Comment: No, this isn't JSON, it's just creating javascript objects. JSON is a specific string format which allows a limited subset of javascript syntax to be represented - for instance JSON can't represent functions

Comment: It's just an illustration of a well organized object literal.  You would also probably have an `events` object with `keys` and `mouse` objects that have functions to create your event handlers, and whatever else you might need.

Answer (score 1):

You could [create plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Answer (score 1):

How about just splitting your code into multiple functions which you call in document.ready? You could also group these into objects, or use one of the OO approaches such as [JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/). I don't think this has much to do with jQuery, by the way, it's just general code structuring.

Comment: Ah, right. I believe you are correct about this being not specific to jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

Or [jQuery Ui Widgets](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Developer_Guide), which goes one step further

Answer (score 0):

Create plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myCustomPlugin = function() {
        // My code here
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

For javascript in general, you can just use functions/objects, see [this](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/).

For jquery, as mentioned above to create a plugin by both komar and darin...

Answer (score 0):

jQuerj is very useful for dom management and for simple xhr. But if you want to create some big application I suggest to change javascript library to adopt some more "enterprise" library like dojotoolkit or yui.